# www-data user unable to import installed python modules

Tags: php, python, linux, webserver, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying create a web-server which ultimately calls a python script ("MyScript.py") from PHP code with the following command

```php
echo exec("MyScript.py ....some arguments")
```

MyScript.py actually contains a code which uses RDkit and other modules like numpy.
When I run this MyScript.py from user (MKT)....it works like a charm.

But the problem arises when it get executed from PHP script from server.
The error message in /var/www/log/apache2/error.log is as follows:

```
ImportError: No module named rdkit
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./preditar/preditar.py", line 7, in <module>
from rdkit import Chem
```

My rdkit is installed in /opt/RDKit_2013_06_1/rdkit/ and this the following the result if run them from MKT user

```
MKT@mypc$ python -v
```

and then in python environment:

```
import rdkit
```

Here is the output:

```
import rdkit # precompiled from /opt/RDKit_2013_06_1/rdkit/\__init__.pyc
```

I think user www-data which executes this do not have access to this module...then how to import this in MyScript.py???

Note: When I modify MyScript.py to a simple script which just create a file and write data to it...it works properly without any issue that means I don't have any problem related to  permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like problem with Python import search path. Try to change the import like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/opt/RDKit_2013_06_1")
import rdkit
```

Comment: yes I done that...but as RdKit is installed in some other folder it needs me to add following to environment variable.
'_export RDBASE=/opt/RDKit_2013_06_1_;'

_export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$RDBASE/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH_

_export PYTHONPATH=$RDBASE:$PYTHONPATH_
Please suggest me how to do this...???

Comment: Solved that problem too........for other folks you can refer to this post [http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1546404]

Comment: Good to hear! BTW in Python you can set env variables using `os.environ` or `os.putenv()`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ

Answer (score 0):

Adding the missing path found for user ubuntu to user www-data via sys.path.insert was not scalable, nor possible (since the ubuntu user path is inaccessible to the www-data user), so the best way was to install the python modules (in this case, rdkit) in a way that will be accessible to the www-data user

`sudo mkdir /var/www/.local`

`sudo mkdir /var/www/.cache`

`sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/.local`

`sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/.cache`

`sudo -H -u www-data pip install rdkit`

https://nocurve.com/2018/04/23/running-python-script-from-php-as-www-data/